# PHP & SQL Server Query : Max(Dates) for particular Date

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I want to build a query to find latest contract date on that particular date.

```
Contract Date:   Tank No

 01/05/2014      1
 12/05/2014      1
 01/06/2014      1
 01/07/2014      1
```

Chosen Date:
21/05/2014

Output Latest Contract Date for 21/05/2014 :
12/05/2014

FYI, I am using MS SQL SERVER 2005 SP4

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX([Contract Date]) AS [Contract Date]
FROM Table1
WHERE [Contract Date] <= '21/05/2014'
```